# Select grand child in array knockout

Tags: javascript, array, knockout.js

I'm trying to select a grand child from an array in an array.

If it was C# I would have wrote something like below

```
SubSteps.Select(item => item.First(subitem => subitem == 1)).First();
```

I have code that works, but I'm not sure it is the best way to do it:

```
ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SubSteps(),
        function (item) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.SubSteps(),
                function (subItem) { return subItem.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage'); });
        }).SubSteps(), function (item) {
            return item.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
        })
```

Is there a method I can use that I've never heard of perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

First off, your indentation is terrible, your code is far more readable like this:

```
ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SubSteps(),
  function(item) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.SubSteps(),
      function(subItem) {
        return subItem.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
      });
  }).SubSteps(), function(item) {
  return item.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
})
```

Second, you are retrieving your subitem twice, because you loose track of it, simply use a 'local global' and assign your subitem to it.

```
var needle, found;
ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SubSteps(),
  function(item) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.SubSteps(),
      function(subItem) {
        found = subItem.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
        if(found) {
          needle = subItem;
        }
        return found;
      });
  });
```

or, if you dont mind some sorcery (don't do this at work!)

```
var needle, found;
ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.SubSteps(),
  function(item) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(item.SubSteps(),
      function(subItem) {
        found = subItem.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
        return found && (needle = subItem), found;
      });
  });
```

Furthemore, you should consider caching `localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage')` and you should consider implementing old skool loops so that you can exit immediately.

Comment: Thank you. The intendention is better in my IDE, but broke here. About the rest of the code worked really good. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use recursion to simplify your code, unless the grandchildren have children that you want to avoid, this should work.

```
function findLastWizard(arr) {
    var subArrayOrItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(arr, function(item) {
        return item.InternalName == localStorage.getItem('lastWizardPage');
    });

    if(subArrayOrItem.SubSteps) {
        return findLastWizard(subArrayOrItem.SubSteps());
    }

    return subArrayOrItem;
}


findLastWizard(self.SubSteps())
```